# inputType="File" upload image by javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have problem uploading image file in my ASP.NET page.

My form is dynamically generated and I used ajax/jquery to send the data to my code behind

My Form:

```
    return "<div class='item'>" +
        "<h3>Create Account For New Staff</h3>" +
        "<p>Fill in staff's particulars in the form below</p>" +
        "<div style='width: 70%;'>" +
        "<table class='style1'><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>NRIC:</td><td><input required type='text' id='newNRIC' value='' placeholder='NRIC' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>Name:</td><td><input required type='text' id='newName' value='' placeholder='Name' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>Gender:</td><td><select><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='Female'>Female</option></select></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>DOB:</td><td><input required type='date' name='DOB' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>Address:</td><td><input required type='text' id='newAddress' value='' placeholder='Address' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>Email:</td><td><input required type='text' id='newEmail' value='' placeholder='Email' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>ContactNo:</td><td><input required type='text' id='newContact' value='' placeholder='Contact Number' /></td></tr><tr>" +
        "<td class='style2'>Image:</td><td><input type='file' name='newProfilePic' accept='image/*'></td></tr><tr><td class='style2'>&nbsp;</td>" +
        "<td><button class='btn' type='button' onclick='addStaffModalSubmit()'>Submit</button></td></tr></table></div></div>"
```

And the code to upload:

```
        var newNRIC = document.getElementById('newNRIC').value;
        var newName = document.getElementById('newName').value;
        var newGender = document.getElementById('newGender').value;
        var newDOB = document.getElementById('newDOB').value;
        var newAddress = document.getElementById('newAddress').value;
        var newEmail = document.getElementById('newEmail').value;
        var newContact = document.getElementById('newContact').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/addStaff",
            data: {
                newNRIC: newNRIC,
                newName: newName,
                newGender: newGender,
                newDOB: newDOB,
                newAddress: newAddress,
                newEmail: newEmail,
                newContact: newContact
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Successfully added staff");
            }
        });
```

But I do not know how to do this for fileupload

```
  <input type='file' name='newProfilePic' accept='image/*'>
```

I'm thinking of uploading it by javascript and send the filepath to my c# code behind.
Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: by using the [HTML 5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), and, here's a [demo I like to use](http://html5demos.com/file-api)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is it possible to send the xhr.send(file) into the database instead of sending it to a php page?

Comment: You need something inbetween you and the database to establish the connection, this requires a server side language such as php.